# Common Lisp vector printing: Vector axis is not zero: 1

Tags: arrays, vector, common-lisp, sbcl

This is the first time I have ever seen this compiler error does anyone know what it is? and why my function can't print my nested vectors.

```
(defvar *col-lookup* #.(let ((ht (make-hash-table)))
                             (loop for (key . value) in
                                  '(
                                    (A . 0) (B . 1) (C . 2)
                                    (D . 3) (E . 4) (F . 5) (G . 6))  
                                do (setf (gethash key ht) value))
                             ht))

    ;; vector of vectors
    (defparameter *game-board* 
(make-array 7 :initial-element (make-array 0 :initial-element 0)))

    ;;make move lookup character in table then push X onto vector of value of key
    (defun move (c)
     (let ((place (gethash c *col-lookup*)))
        (cond ((oddp *turn-count*)
           (push "X" (aref *game-board* place))
            (incf *turn-count*))
           ((push "O" (aref *game-board* place))
            (incf *turn-count*)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a very peculiar vector of vectors with the code:

```
(make-array 7 :initial-element (make-array 0 :initial-element 0)))
```

This code will create a vector of 7 elements, each of them a vector with 0 elements (i.e. an empty vector) (and note that giving the initial-element to 0 is useless because there are no elements to assign). If you print it you should see:

```
#(#() #() #() #() #() #() #())
```

which means exactly this, a vector with seven empty vectors. So if you try to access the internal vector with something like `(aref (aref *game-board*) 1) 2)` you get an error.

Finally note that in the code of the function `move` you use:

```
(push "X" (aref *game-board* place))
```

whose effect is not of modifying the internal vector at place `place`, but of replace the old value of `(aref *game-board* place)` with a `cons` of the string `"X"` and the old value of `(aref *game-board* place)`, the empty vector.

Comment: You are exactly right, I am making a structure that looks like this after it is populated: ("O" "X" . #()) 
("O" "X" . #()) 
("X" "O" "O" "X" . #()) 
("X" "O" "X" "O" . #()) 
("O" "X" . #()) 
("X" . #()) 
("X" "O" . #()) The reason I use :inital-element 0 is so I have something to pop objects onto inside the empty array lol. it's such a hack.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to print my vector of vectors by simply looping over it once. I still do not know what that error was but I haven't ran into it since.

```
(defun print-game ()
  (loop for i from 0 to 6 do
       (print (aref *game-board* i))))
```